# Android Application - How to get Google Maps API to use animateTo()?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an Android Application and i have the google maps up and running on the screen. However, I want to snap to a point when I first load up the map. I.e. London.

I have searched around and tried different methods but I cannot get it to work.

public class MinuteMapActivity extends MapActivity {

```
MapView mapView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //the methods on the map are initialised here
    SnapToMap();
```

}

```
    MapController SnapToMap = mapView.getController();
    String coordinates[] = {"1.352566007", "103.78921587"}; //these values are from a website, how do I get the co-ordinates from google maps for i.e. London?
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

    GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (lat * 1E6),
            (int) (lng * 1E6));
    SnapToMap.animateTo(gp);
    SnapToMap.setZoom(15);
    mapView.invalidate();
}
```

This is what I have wrote. Am I doing something wrong? It keeps on coming up with a run time error and closes the application. Do I need to add something to the XML Layout? Can somebody also explain what mapView.invalidate() does? I sourced parts of this code from mobiforge.com

LogCat results:

```
12-05 01:15:07.245: D/AndroidRuntime(18945): Shutting down VM
12-05 01:15:07.245: W/dalvikvm(18945): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{application.project.minutemap/application.project.minutemap.MinuteMapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at application.project.minutemap.MinuteMapActivity.SnapToMap(MinuteMapActivity.java:61)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at application.project.minutemap.MinuteMapActivity.onCreate(MinuteMapActivity.java:24)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
12-05 01:15:07.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18945):    ... 11 more
```

NullPointerException at Line 61:  MapController snapToMap = mapView.getController();

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Why did you tag this as 'iPhone'? I removed that tag as it was incorrect; only tag your questions for the topics they are relevant to.

Comment: The runtime error will tell you what to do. Look in logcat to get the stack trace and post it here.

Comment: Are you using `SnapToMap` as both a method name and a variable name?? FYI in Java the convention is to use a lowercase letter as the first character in variable and method names. Also, your code formatting is confusing, could you make sure it matches what you have? Also, the exception points to a null pointer at line 61, so please post that all by itself.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the file so that variable and method names start with lowercase (no wonder in tutorials they are lowercase all the time.) I took out the irrelevant parts of the code, only the parts that are needed and are not working have been added.

Comment: NullPointerException at Line 61: MapController snapToMap = mapView.getController();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not initalising your mapView.  If you have it in your layout xml you need to find it with somthing like.

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
```

Alternativly you can new it in in code with somthing like.

```
mapView = new MapView(this, "Your map API key here...n");
```

You will then need to add it to your view.

Comment: You are amazing! I initialised it and it worked! Mate, I love you.

Comment: You should learn to work it out yourself.  The stacktrace gives you the exact line of interest.  Unless it's somthing like and int or float you always have to get your object set from somewhere.

Comment: The stacktrace? Is that LogCat? It only told me about NullPointerException. I'm fairly new, I read the online documentation about the NullPointerException but it didn't really lead to any resolvement.

Comment: Null pointer meens you are accessing somthing that has not been asigned.  Sometimes you get them returned to you though from a call in which case you can programaticaly check with if(foo == null) befor doing foo.bar().  You will get used to them...